# problem books in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, big-list, book-recommendation

There are many excellent problem books in real analysis. I'm looking for a problem book in functional analysis or a book which contains a lot of problems in functional analysis (Easy and hard problems) to which a complete solution manual is readily available .

Comment: I thought that Halmos' "A Hilbert Space Problem Book" was quite nice. I believe it also has a section with hints and then another one with more or less full solutions.

Comment: You might want to have a look at **Textbook of Functional Analysis: A Problem-oriented Approach** by V. K. Krishnan. You might also want to review some of the recommendation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/good-book-for-self-study-of-functional-analysis

Comment: Simply searching in Google Books for 
[exercises functional analysis](http://books.google.com/books?q=exercises+functional+analysis) or 
[problems functional analysis](http://books.google.com/books?q=problems+functional+analysis) 
might provide you some suggestions. (Of course, you will have judge for yourself which of them seem reasonable.)

Answer (score 2):

[A $C_p$-Theory Problem Book: Topological and Function Spaces](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=EcINw8FHIAoC) by Vladimir V. Tkachuk (2011). (I think all problems are solved in the main book.)

Also, this [link at mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13555/a-book-for-problems-in-functional-analysis) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations . I think it's a very good book ,but I'm interested in a more applied point of view that's applicable to physics . Also ,at a first glance that book doesn't cover operator theory on hilbert space.

Comment: It is true that Tkachuk's book has solutions to all problems given there. And it seems to be a very good book, as far as I can say. However, I would classify it general topology rather than functional analysis.

Answer (score 2):

[Theorems and Problems in Functional Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038790638X) has a lot of problems with hints and solutions.

Comment: this book is hard

Answer (score 1):

The book Fabian, Habala, Hájek, Montesinos, Zizler: *Banach Space Theory, The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Analysis* (CMS Books in Mathematics) has many exercises at the end of each chapter. It does not have solutions, but most of the exercises come with some hint (in some cases rather detailed). Google Books [link](https://books.google.sk/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C), DOI: [10.1007/978-1-4419-7515-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4419-7515-7)

This book was also recommended in some other posts on this site:

- [References for Banach Space Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610076/references-for-banach-space-theory)
- [Book suggestion geometry of Banach spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901030/book-suggestion-geometry-of-banach-spaces/901213#901213)

Answer (score 0):

Bernard Gelbaum's *Problems in Real and Complex Analysis* has a chapter on topological vector spaces, which are functional analysis problems.