# Book suggestion geometry of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, book-recommendation

I am studying geometry of Banach spaces and applications in metric fixed point theory. Does anyone have a good recommendation of books//lectures/resources/etc.?
Thanks.

Comment: if you are looking for fixed point theory you should look into the direction of non-linear functional analysis

Comment: I am studding geometry of Banach spaces and sometimes I like know applications of geometry of Banach spaces

Answer (score 11):

These are the books I recommend:

- [A short course on Banach space theory. N. L. Carothers](http://bookfi.org/book/1026166). A friendly introduction into geometry of Banach spaces
- [An Introduction to Banach Space Theory Graduate Texts in Mathematics. Robert E. Megginson](http://bookfi.org/book/1155512). A more academic, but still very basic exposition.
- [Topics in Banach space theory. F. Albiac, N. Kalton](http://bookfi.org/book/1047151). Though this is still a textbook, it contains a lot. Mostly for future Banach space specialists.
- [The isometric theory of classical Banach spaces. H. E. Lacey](http://bookfi.org/book/1504900). If you are interesed geometric effects concerned with exact value of the norm.
- [Banach space theory. The basis for linear and non-linear analysis. M. Fabian, P. Habala, P. Hajek, V. Montesinos, V. Zizler](http://bookfi.org/book/1208933). It is more an encyclopedia than a textbook. Contains much more than you ever want to know.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very helpful! Although "contains much more than you ever want to know": Probably not because I want to know everything ;)

Comment: All the links are broken. Please update your answer.