# Good reference for Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

Sorry for possibly duplicate post, I am interested in self-studying functional analysis. To give you a hint of my background; I've taken a class on real analysis (where we covered first half of Baby Rudin) and also a class on Fourier analysis (where we used Stein's Fourier analysis together with parts of his real analysis book for measure theory and to prove a.e. type of results).

Given this background, which book would you recommend me to attack? Thanks!

Comment: @Jp McCarthy: I didn't see any functional analysis references in the comments or first few answers. Why would you consider this question a duplicate of that question?

Comment: Sorry I meant http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/good-book-for-self-study-of-functional-analysis?rq=1

Comment: I personally like Brezis's book on functional analysis, but I suspect as a first step, you'll need a better introduction to real analysis topics for any substantial functional analysis book.

Comment: There are way too many good books on functional analysis so all the answers will be very subjective. Here are my subjective two cents: I really really like a recent [Linear and Nonlinear Functional Analysis with Applications](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Nonlinear-Functional-Analysis-Applications/dp/1611972582/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1490622457&sr=8-1&keywords=linear+and+nonlinear+functional+analysis) because it is 1) mostly self contained, 2) covers most of the necessary stuff, 3) has very detailed proofs without usual "clearly". Check this out.

Comment: @Artem this is indeed a remarkable book, thanks for the reference.