# Does it always happen $\|ax+by\|=1 \implies |a+b|\leq 1?$ for $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ (where $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I am new in functional analysis. I was reading a theory related to unit ball in Banach space. While studying the norm attainment set of points I met with a confusion:

For a finite dimensional real Banach space $\mathbb{X}$ and for $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$, do always $\|ax+by\|=1 \implies |a+b|\leq 1? $ (where $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$)

I think the answer is yes. Also I have a doubt on whether the statement is true in any normed linear space. I have tried with my limited knowledge to prove it by contradiction i.e., by considering $|a+b|>1$ trying to find two distinct elements $x, y$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ such that $\|ax+by\|\ne 1$ but I could not able to proceed. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Thank you all for the quick suggestions but all the examples are in Hilbert space. What will happen if $\mathbb{X}$ is not a Hilbert space? Is the statement still wrong?

Comment: No, take $x = (1,0)$, $y = (0,1)$ and $a = b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, then $||ax+by|| = 1$ but $|a+b| = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2} > 1$

Comment: And an even dumber counterexample in $\Bbb R$: $x=1$, $y=-1$, $a=2$, $b=1$.

Comment: Hi,wellcome to MSE : does it help$$1=(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)\geq(ax+by)^2,
$$ ?

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comment on this. It really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TZakrevskiy's comment shows you how to construct a counterexample in any normed space.

Let $y = -x$ with $\Vert x \Vert = 1$. Then $$\Vert ax+by \Vert = \Vert (a-b)x\Vert = |a-b|.$$ Thus, we can let $b = a - 1$ with $a>1$ arbitrary to get a counterexample.

Comment: Got it @Ennar. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Tutun, you are welcome. Here you can see something broader, restricting any norm to one-dimensional real subspace gives you $\mathbb R$ isometrically. So, if you can find counterexample in $\mathbb R$, you can find it in any normed space.

Comment: Wow what a nice observation @Ennar!! Can you suggest any books or something so that I can develop my thinking like the way you have developed?? It will be very helpful for me. Thank you in advance. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: @Tutun, I'm not a functional analyst so unfortunately I can't recommend you any books in English, but you can easily find book recommendations on this site. For example, there is this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7512/122131.

Comment: Thank you @Ennar. Thank you very much for your suggestion.